# Deduction of cyclic relation in thermodynamics.

Tags: partial-derivative, physics

I want know what theorem I need to prove
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{\partial \,x}{\partial \,y}\right)_{z}\left(\frac{\partial \,y}{\partial \,z}\right)_{x} = -\left(\frac{\partial \,x}{\partial \,z}\right)_{y}
\end{equation*}
implies
\begin{equation*}
\left(\frac{\partial \,x}{\partial \,y}\right)_{z}\left(\frac{\partial \,y}{\partial \,z}\right)_{x}\left(\frac{\partial \,z}{\partial \,x}\right)_{y} = -1.
\end{equation*}
What is the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) to show that
$$
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_y = \left[\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_y\right]^{-1}.
$$